# Не обрабатывать форму при загрузке страницы

Tags: python, django

Функция рендерящая главную страницу из шаблона. На странице форма. Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы не обрабатывалась пустая форма?

```
def main(request):
    list = Model.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        list = formWatcher(form)
        return render_to_response('main.html', {'model_list': list, 'form': SearchForm})
    else:
        return render_to_response('main.html', {'model_list': list, 'form': SearchForm})
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужна проверка `GET` запроса, вы и так через него обращаетесь, если не используете ajax.
Задайте атрибут `name` для `input` тега:

```
<form action='', method='get'>
    <input name='value' type='text>
</form>
```

И обработайте его во `view`:

```
if 'value' in request.GET and request.GET['value']:
    value = request.GET['value']
```

Дальше обрабатывайте данные запроса как вам нужно